# calling angular controller from another controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on angularjs application. I have multiple angular controllers in my js. I want to call the angular controller from another angular controller .
Please find the code below.I want to call myControllerOne from myControllerTwo by passing sid and zone values from myControllerTwo. Any suggestions would be helpful.

```
app.controller('myControllerOne',function($rootScope,$scope,$uibModal,MyTestService,sid,zone)  {
        //MyTestService.getResults() hits the backend code and get the results
        MyTestService.getResults(sid,zone).then(
            function(response) {
                $scope.responseData = response;
                //logic
                //
            })
    });

app.controller('myControllerTwo', function ($rootScope,$scope,$uibModal,MyTestService) {
   function loadData() {
        MyTestService.getServiceDataResults().then(
            function (response) {
               var cb = function(start, end, label) {
                   var sid = response.sid;
                   var zone = response.zone;
                      $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
                     //i want to call myControllerOne here by passing sid and zone values for this controller
                }
                var optionSet1 = {
                    startDate: moment().subtract(1, 'days'),
                    endDate: moment().subtract(1, 'days'),
                    minDate: minDate,
                    maxDate: maxDate,
                    dateLimit: {
                        days: 60
                    },
                    showDropdowns: true,
                    showWeekNumbers: true,
                    timePicker: false,
                    timePickerIncrement: 1,
                    timePicker12Hour: true,
                    ranges: {
                        'Today': [moment(), moment()],
                        'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
                        'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
                        'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
                        'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
                        'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
                    },
                    opens: 'left',
                    buttonClasses: ['btn btn-default'],
                    applyClass: 'btn-small btn-primary',
                    cancelClass: 'btn-small',
                    format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
                    separator: ' to ',
                    locale: {
                        applyLabel: 'Submit',
                        cancelLabel: 'Clear',
                        fromLabel: 'From',
                        toLabel: 'To',
                        customRangeLabel: 'Custom',
                        daysOfWeek: ['Su', 'Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa'],
                        monthNames: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
                        firstDay: 1
                    }
                };

                $('#reportrange span').html(moment().subtract(1, 'days').format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + moment().subtract(1, 'days').format('MMMM D, YYYY'));

                $('#reportrange').daterangepicker(optionSet1, cb);

                $('#reportrange').on('show.daterangepicker', function() {
                     console.log("show event fired");
                });
                $('#reportrange').on('hide.daterangepicker', function() {
                     console.log("hide event fired");
                });
                $('#reportrange').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
                    console.log("apply event fired, start/end dates are " + picker.startDate.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + " to " + picker.endDate.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
                });
                $('#reportrange').on('cancel.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
                    console.log("cancel event fired");
                });
            })

    }
     loadData();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you ever need to pass values between different Controllers, consider instead using a Service to hold the shared data and then injecting it as a dependency in both controllers.

Additionally, if there's functionality in one controller that you want available in another, then that functionality should be lifted up into a service. In your example, instead of using `myControllerTwo` to manipulate the response returned by your service, manipulate the response within the service and then return the processed data. You can even cache the processed data so that `myControllerOne` can access it at any time by calling `MyTestService.getResults(sid,zone)`. `MyTestService` can then retrieve the results and return it to the controller, all without making one controller a dependency of another.

You CAN [access a parent controller from a child controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#intercomponent-communication) via a Component's `require` property but honestly this should be avoided as it tightly couples components and can lead to headaches later on.

Answer (score 1):

Can you call one controller from another? **YES**
Should you call one controller from another? **NO**

**Possible Solution:**
Whatever IAmKale said is absolutely right and that should be the solution.
Hence:

1. Define two controllers separately and share data through a Service(Services are Singleton Objects and hence can be used to share data between *controllers*).
2. In the HTML you can call one controller inside another(still a bad practice)